# How to set up UCMA 4 development environment without interfering with the working Lync Server?

Tags: lync-2013, ucma

I am trying to install UCMA 4.0 SDK and it looks like one of the prerequisites is a Lync Server 2013 (Bootstrapper Prerequisites Installer Package, Core Components).

Is this supposed to be a fully configured server ? I have a running Lync Server on the Network... on a server, hovewer, I don't want to develop on it. Will the Lync Server installed during installation of the SDK be just a couple of required libs and stuff or is it supposed to be a working Server, i.e. will it interfere with the running Server in the Network ?

Is there maybe a how-to-setup-ucma-dev-environment-for-noobs tutorial out there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need a full Lync/Skype environment to install the UCMA SDK and develop locally, however will need to have a properly configured application server that is registered with your Lync environment to be able to run your UCMA application.

And no the SDK will not deploy Lync.

To be honest to develop a UCMA app all you really need is the Microsoft.RTc.Collaboration.dll usually found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft UCMA 4.0\SDK\Core\Bin once the SDK is installed.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are going to run as development server, install visual studio first.
2. Run UCMA 4.0
3. Install Core components by navigating to the following path and run OCSCore.msi
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Lync Server 2013\Deployment\cache\4.0.7577.0\Setup\
4. After that, go the following path (Cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Lync Server 2013\Deployment) and run bootstrapper from command prompt>>
   Bootstrapper.exe /BootstrapLocalMgmt /MinCache

After all the steps, you can start provisioning for your application.